# visiting other temples after going to Shaneeshwar Temple

Tags: temple, worship

I heard that one should return home after going to Shani Temple. Tomorrow I planning to go to Thirunallar Shani temple after that Vaitheeshwaran temple and few others. Is it ok to go to Shani Temple first and others later. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

अन्यप्रदेशात्स्वगृहं प्रविष्टस्तदीयवारे स नरः सुखी स्यात् ।
गृहाद् गतो यो न पुनः प्रयाति तस्मै नमः श्रीरविनन्दनाय ॥ ७॥

This is the 7th Shloka of Shaishchara Ashtaka by Dasharatha embedded in the Brahmandha Purana.

Translation: The one who enters one's own house from another nation on his day (Saturday) becomes happy. **After reaching the house, one who doesn't again leave**, to that son of the sun (Shanishchara), I do Namaskaara.

After reaching the Shanaishchara temple, just head home (without leaving for the whole day). Don't go to the Shanaishchara temple first, keep it for last.